# Disconnect keyboard in Ubuntu Studio 23.10 Wayland

Tags: keyboard

The keyboard disconnects all the time in Ubuntu Studio 23.10 Wayland, I am editing video with Kdenlive or images with Inkscape and every so often I am left without a keyboard, only the mouse works.